# pass value swt to swf

Tags: flash

I have a two swf, index and gallery. I am call gallery.swf in to index.swf.

loadMovie("image_gallery/gallery.swf",1);

I want to make pass value from gallery.swf.

How can I do this.

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Maybe you should edit the question so it doesn't say "swt"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send values in the URL, like this:

```
loadMovie("image_gallery/gallery.swf?variableName=value",1);
```